# Incoming Connections Getting Dropped with sshuttle running

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

I am running the traffic from my docker container through sshuttle to a remote server, which is working great with this command:

```
sshuttle -l 0.0.0.0 -r user@server 0/0 -v
```

The problem is that I need incoming connections to be allowed to reach my local server via the remote server's ip address and a specific port. I've tried creating an additional  ssh tunnel via

```
ssh -NR 0.0.0.0:43523:localhost:43523
```

This *almost* works, as the incoming connections show up in the sshuttle verbose logs, but the connection never establishes (connection timed out from the client side).

Here are the iptables rules created by sshuttle at runtime:

```
iptables -t nat -N sshuttle-12300
iptables -t nat -F sshuttle-12300
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -j sshuttle-12300
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j sshuttle-12300
iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j RETURN -m ttl --ttl 63
iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j RETURN -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL
iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --to-ports 12300
```

So my question is: What is causing the incoming connections to not work? And how can I fix it?